# Use EL expression only for method call,but ignore the method return value

Tags: java, jsp, el

Is it possible to run a method with EL expression but ignore its return value(not showing it on the page)?In my case,i am calling an add method on a collection that return true/false if the element was successfully added.I want to be able to call that method,but i don't want to output true/false value on the page.And of course i don't want to use scriptlets for that.

```
<jsp:useBean id="errors" scope="request" class="java.util.ArrayList" />

${errors.add("The username or password is incorrect.")}
```

Comment: You better use a normal Java class such as a Servlet to put Java code logic in. The `<jsp:useBean>` does not allow a proper MVC approach. Don't use it.

Comment: @BalusC in my case i don't really know how to do that.I have a tag file(called header) that accepts a collection of messages to display at the end.But the problem is that with form-based authentication i can't  add any attribute to use in the jsp.I could solve this with filter i think,but i am trying to find an easier way.Isn't there any way to at least hide the input ?